# GnuPG keeps looking for my dead smart card

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp, smartcard

My smart card died (physically). I made offline backups of my keys, and those are successfully imported back into GnuPG. However, it keeps asking for the key whenever I try to decrypt using the keys. I've even tried this on a fresh machine and yet I've had no luck getting GnuPG to use the local secret keys instead of the dead card ones...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to delete the old card keys and import them again.

First of all, make sure the backup actually contains the secret keys you're looking for:

```
gpg --list-packets [backup-file]
```

You should find several `:secret [sub] key packet` lines. They should not be followed (some intermediate lines might occur) by `gnu-divert-to-card S2K...` or `gnu-dummy S2K....` lines, which indicate GnuPG-specific secret key stubs for card or other offline keys.

### Recovering the Whole Key

If you have all secret keys together in your backup, that's not an issue and you can simply run `gpg --delete-secret-key [key-id]` and `gpg --import` your backup.

### Merging with (new) Subkeys

If you changed your secret keys after this date (for example, added new subkeys), you'll have to merge the keys. This is not an issue with GnuPG 2.1 or newer, which finally implemented secret key merging. For older versions of GnuPG, you'll have to manually take apart the individual OpenPGP packets (`gpgsplit`) and put them together in the right order again. Better upgrade to GnuPG 2.1, which will make things *much* easier.

Delete the card keys through `gpg --edit-key [key-id]`, and then use `gpg --import` to import the (missing) subkeys. GnuPG 2.1 might get installed as `gpg2`. Be aware GnuPG 2.1 stores the secret keys in the `pubring.gpg` file, so GnuPG 1 or 2.0 will not find it unless you export and import it again to the old release.

Comment: Thank you. Your specific advice about gnu-divert-to-card S2K confirmed my worst fear: I accidentally backed up the stubs, not the secret keys.

Lesson learned for the future: make permanent backups before copying keys to cards.

Comment: Another thing to add when doing backups: actually try the recovery procedure from time to time, but at least once to verify everything's contained.

Comment: Sage advice! It's absolutely the kind of thing I would usually do. The reason I didn't? I went to the effort of never letting the private keys exist outside of an air-gapped machine. Unfortunately the effort of spinning that up to do any regular checks meant that I skipped it and ended up in this mess. Lesson learned!

I was at least able to revoke the key. It's not a disaster for my identity, and my encrypted documents were just passwords, which I was able to reset. The biggest disaster was losing my two-factor codes; encrypted by the key that broke.